# How run task from command line in feathersjs app?

Tags: feathersjs

I need do some internal work in feathersjs app. I need something like *mytask.js*  file, that will have access into app services and do something operations with data. Task will start from command line:

```
node mytask.js
```

How I can implement this?

Answer (score 2):

The Feathers app in a generated application and be required like any other module through the `src/app.js` file. In `mytask.js`:

```js
const app = require('./app'); // adjust path

// Top level wrapper to use async/await
(async () => {
  const messages = await app.service('messages').find();
})();
```

In some cases you might want to call [app.setup()](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/application.html#setup-server) e.g. when using Sequelize (example [here](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-sequelize#1-build-a-test-file)).